# jQuery disable draggable fade out

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

In my script i have 2 buttons, one in order to enable the draggable and the another to disable it. Here is how ive done this

```
$('#Enable').click(function(){
   $("#sortable li").draggable({
                disabled : false
            });
});

$('#Disable').click(function(){
   $("#sortable li").draggable({
                disabled : true
            });
});
```

My problem is that when i disable the draggable feature, all my elements are fading out a little bit. Is there any way to prevent this fading out every time i disable the draggable?
Here is my code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GbQH2/7/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The styling when `disabled` comes from the jQueryUI's CSS.

Simply add this to your css:

```
 li.ui-state-disabled.ui-draggable-disabled { opacity : 1;}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5KrAv/

Comment: Never mind, it does work in IE, I just had to add `filter: alpha(opacity = 50);`.